# How to run and use Xcode 3 and Xcode 4 under OS X 10.7 Lion?

Tags: xcode4, xcode3.2, osx-lion

I am looking for a full guide on how to trick Xcode3 to run under Lion.

I am aware that Apple does not support this, but this doesn't meant it's impossible, it's just not supported.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I upgraded my dev environment to Lion. I am only doing it this way because I'm in a crunch and have some issues with Xcode 4.

I'm just sharing what I did and the issues I encountered, not recommending anything:

1. I made sure I could build & launch my Apps in 10.6.8 using Xcode 3.2.x.
2. I upgraded my development machine to Lion 10.7.1.
3. I can build all my SW products with Xcode 3.2.x.

BUT, the debugger seems unhappy with some things... Though I can step and break, I can't evaluate some expressions. For example, the twist pane won't display contents of complex structures.

I'm wondering if others have debugger issues with the 3.2.x Xcode (GDB) on Lion?

Thanks,

Rick

Answer (score 1):

First you have to obtain the Xcode 3.2.6 install to work. The installer is not going to work on Lion so you have two alternatives:

- Run it from another partition where you have 10.6
- Path the installer in order to make it run on Lion by following [this guide](http://anatomicwax.tumblr.com/post/8064949186/installing-xcode-3-2-6-on-lion-redux)

Also here are some other **things you may have to clean inside the xcode projects**:

1. Remove lines like `ARCHS = arm7` because it will fail to build for Simulator. Best is to let Xcode use defaults (all supported archs).
2. Check for `SDKROOT = ...`, it should be only `iphoneos`, `macosx` or undefined (not `""`). Keep in mind that the SDK you are building against is not necessary the minimum required SDK for running the application. It's ok if SDKROOT is missing from Xcode project files but it's not ok if it does contain a path or `""`.
3. Remove any `GCC_VERSION = ...`